# Finding the distance between two lines in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, distance, proximity, parallel-lines

I want to find two lines which are very close to each other within the same layer (spatially).

See the image below where there are two lines which are very close (distance of ~18 cm). I wanted to find such features which are very close and belong to the same layer. These lines generally run parallel to each other and do not intersect.

[image]

---

After @Babel’s answer I used `overlay_nearest' but it looks like even though the features having distance more than 1 meters it is getting selected.

Is there another configuration i need to change?

See below screenshots.

[image]

[image]

I'm using below CRS system.

[image]

Comment: You already found a possible solution: Look for them. I guess this is not feasible, but then you have to provide some details please. How do you define "close"? Do you want to delete or snape or merge them? What have you tried? How large is your dataset? Is this a one time task, or a repetitive one?

Comment: You may try to buffer the line by a very short distance and select intersecting buffer

Answer (score 6):

If you have no intersecting lines, use ["Select by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-location) with this expression including [`overlay_nearest()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#overlay-nearest) and change the max_distance:

```
overlay_nearest(@layer, max_distance:=1)
```

Be aware: your layer must be saved in a CRS using meters as units, thus don't use a geographic CRS like `EPSG:4326` (WGS84). In this case, first reproject your layer.

*The two yellow lines are selected (their closest points having a distance of ca. 0.5 m), the others have a distance of more than 1 meter:*

[image]

If you have **lines that intersect**, you have to use another expression: wehre the lines cross, the have a distance of 0 and thus would always be selected. For this reason, we want to exclude cases of lines that intersect and only consider **lines that do not touch**.

This can be done with this expression - change `max_distance` to the distance you want and replace `100` in `limit:=100` with a number that corresponds to the max. number of other lines crossing each line and add 1 (increase the number for better results, but with huge layers, it might get slow):

```
array_sum(
    array_foreach (
        overlay_nearest( 
            @layer, 
            $geometry,
            max_distance:=1,
            limit:=100
        ),
        if ( 
            length (
                shortest_line( 
                    $geometry, 
                    @element
                )
            )>0,
            1,
            0
        )
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Babel for guiding me here. I used the `overlay_nearest` as mostly in my use case the lines are parallel. But looks I'm doing some mistake. even though the distance is more than 1 meter the features are getting selected.

Comment: Updated my original post based on the above answer shared by @Babel.

Comment: @Hussain Khan
 : What CRS are your data in ? Can you share the data or the project?

Comment: CRS is WGS 84 and Authority ID =EPSG:4326

Comment: Thats why you get wrong results: this CRS has units in degrees. Thismakes no sense for measurements. Reproject your data to a CRS that uses meters as units - e.g. the local  UTM zone.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use PyQGIS. This doesnt take the "parallelness" into account, only distance. Although it could be adapted to do so.

```
import itertools #To get all pairwise combinations of lines
lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('lines')[0] #Change
reproject_to = "EPSG:32633" #Change
mindist = 1 #Change

#Reproject so distance is in meters and not degrees. Pick a coordinate system for your location
reprojected = processing.run("native:reprojectlayer", {'INPUT':lyr,
    'TARGET_CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(reproject_to),'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})['OUTPUT']

nearby_lines = []

for l1, l2 in itertools.combinations(reprojected.getFeatures(), 2):
    dist = l1.geometry().distance(l2.geometry())
    if dist <=mindist:
        print('{0} to {1}: {2} m'.format(l1.id(), l2.id(), round(dist,2)))
        nearby_lines.extend([l1.id(), l2.id()])

lyr.select(nearby_lines)
```

[image]